# PHP Delete record from database MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to delete a record, in this case a categories from my forum, from the database based on its id.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['user_level'] == 1)
    {
?>
    <td>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?= ['cat_id']; ?>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remover" />
        </form>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            mysql_query("DELETE FROM categories where cat_id = 'cat_id'");
        }
    ?>
    </td>
<?php
}
?>
```

i cant get a "good" way to do it... :(

EDIT: This is for a programming lesson not a real forum!!

Comment: cat_id should be a PHP variable.

Comment: whats the value in input type hidden, m sure its not a variable.

Comment: you might want to describe your problem in more detail. i.e. "It does not delete" or "an error message is shown" and so on ...

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML Input Field needs a name so it can be identified by your PHP.
Then, in your Code Block where you attempt to delete the category, you need to acces the category id using the [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array.

Another thig you want to do is read up onj the dangers of [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
If you're just playing around with PHP and MySQL at the moment: Go Ahead. But if you actually want to develop, maybe you should read up on a few other things as well, even if it seems like overkill at first: [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).

Nontheless, try this:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['user_level'] == 1)
        {
    ?>
        <td>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="hid_catid" id="hid_catid" value="<?php  echo $cat_id; ?>">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remover" />
            </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                
$query = "DELETE FROM categories where cat_id = '".(int)$_POST['hid_catid']."'";
mysql_query($query);
            }
        ?>
        </td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

--> **hidden field should have name** and id to use

--
Thanks

Comment: What about injection? Deprecated functions?

Comment: Rather unlikely that `value="<?= ['cat_id']; ?>"` will work. a) using `<?=` is not recommended and b) what's `['cat_id']`. And even worse: this code is prone to sql injections.

Comment: sorry, still prone to sql injections. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: And you should be telling the OP to stop using deprecated functions, just use `(int)$_POST['hid_catid']` this will protect from SQL injection in this case

Comment: i did echo the query the only thing that it showed my was "1", thats all, still dont know why the record isnt deleted...

Comment: No echo like this. echo $query = "DELETE FROM categories where cat_id = '".(int)$_POST['hid_catid']."'"; exit; Then you will get query.

Comment: 2 errors. First "Undefined variable: query", second "Fatal error: Function name must be a string"

Comment: Well, with the adjustments in the recent edit of the post, you should be able to simply use `echo $query;die();` to see the query if you put that behind your query definitions. Also, read up on the PHP mysql_error functions to handle errors http://de1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 0):

Your hidden input field needs a name to be accessable after the post. Also I am not sure if `['cat_id']` is the correcty way to reference this variable. Where does it come from?

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cat_id" value="<?= $cat_id ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Remover" />
</form>
```

Then your query has to look like this to correctly grab the id from the post.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM categories where cat_id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cat_id']));
```

Comment: `where cat_id = " . $_POST['cat_id']`: prone to sql injections.